# How does WolframAlpha simplify $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {k+n-1 \choose n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

Working through a Discrete Math proof I was trying to simplify my equation, but I didn't know how to deal with this summation of a selection:
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {k+n-1 \choose n-1}$

I put it into wolframalpha and it simplified it for me, saying:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n - 1} {k + n - 1 \choose n - 1} = {2 n - 1 \choose n - 1}$$
([This link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28k%2Bn-1%29%20choose%20%28n-1%29%2C%20k%3D0%20to%20n-1) should show you the result I got)

That let me simplify enough to finish the problem, but I don't know how wolframalpha got to that answer. We've just begun the basics of this 'choose notation,' but if I need to do some background research to understand why this simplification is valid I'm willing to.

**My Question:** WolframAlpha simplified my equation, but I'd like to understand the work necessary to get that answer.

P.S. I'm new here, I read through the rules but if I'm doing anything wrong be sure to tell me :)

Comment: You're looking for the hockey stick identity.

Comment: It works through a symbolic algebra program. I'm not sure what the exact algorithm is but I don't think the question is right for this site. It may fit in better on the computational mathematics stack but they don't typically do these questions either.

Comment: @rogerl Hmm thanks I'll look into that

Comment: @RyanHowe Sorry, I'll clarify my answer. I'm looking for the mathematical steps to get that answer, not how the computer knows those steps.

Comment: Notice that the hockey stick identity gives you that the sum is equal to $\dbinom{2n-1}n$ which is the same as $\dbinom{2n-1}{n-1}$ since $\dbinom nr=\dbinom n{n-r}$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I can't seem to figure out how the Hockey stick identity applies to my problem, can you show me why it gives that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m} {n+k \choose n} = {n+m+1 \choose n+1}$$
So now we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1+k \choose n-1}$$
$$={n-1+n-1+1\choose n-1+1}$$
$$={2n-1\choose n}$$
Also note that when $0\le n\le 2n-1$, we have
$${2n-1\choose n}={2n-1\choose 2n-1-n}$$
I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks, I see how you got from step to step

Comment: Where does that identity come from though?

Comment: It's an application of the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity). You can also find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Others).